# How to authenticate Facebook user without form?

Tags: php, facebook, oauth

Is there any way I can authenticate a Facebook user without requiring them to connect in the front end? I'm trying to report the number of "likes" for an alcohol-gated page and will need to access the information with an over-21 access token, but do not want to have to log in every time I access the data.

Or is there a way to generate an access token that doesn't expire?

I'm really not that much of an expert with facebook, so any alternatives to these ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I believe you can get an access token that doesn't expire (or at least lasts a lot longer) by requesting the 'offline access' permission from the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're requesting the access token you're going to use to check the Page, request the `offline_access` extended permission and the token won't expire when you/the user logs out.

Comment: ah yes, I totally forgot about this. Thanks!

Comment: Can I rig this up any way on the sever side so that if I visit it in another browser, it won't prompt for login? Or should it just work for the server side script to use the access token from a user that has allowed offline access to get the page's likes?

Comment: You could store the access token you're using server-side and use it multiple times, but I recommend caching the response from the API in this case as if you make a new request to Facebook on every page load, it may run into rate limiting on the Facebook side. Also, you should only use an access token to make API calls on behalf of the user that granted you that token (i.e be extremely careful not to expose content which is gated by demographic to your own users that don't meet that demographic)

Comment: Cool, yeah, I will definitely be caching. I will only ever be using one user, so I shouldn't run into that issue, but thanks! very helpful

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/), when you initially get the `access_token`, add `offline_access` to the list of permissions you're requesting via the `scope` parameter. From the [permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) documentation:

> The set of permissions below basically explain what types of permissions you can ask a u ser in the scope parameter of your auth dialog to get the permissions you need for your app.

So add `offline_access` to the permissions you're requesting in the `scope` parameter:

```
$config = array(
  ...
  "scope" => "offline_access,...",
  ...
);
...
```